# Convert mp3 to ogg via Paperclip (S3) on Heroku

Tags: ruby, audio, heroku, ffmpeg, paperclip

I have a media attribute (from `paperclip`) that can be audio or image.  I use an HTML5 audio player (`jplayer`) for an audio player on the front-end which works well in Chrome and Safari but Firefox has trouble with `mp3` and needs a `ogg` format file.  I see usage of `ffmpeg` but am unsure how to implement to also work on Heroku.  I have tried using [paperclip-ffmpeg](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg) like below but it hasn't been re-formatting the file (have tried format as 'ogv' and 'ogg'):

```
has_attached_file :media, styles: { ogg: { format: 'ogv' } }, processors: [:ffmpeg]
```

Any ideas?